In Google Colab, is it possible to end a section without creating a new one?
In Google Colab notebook, is there a way to end a section without creating a new section?
The goal is to be able to place hidden sections in a notebook, but without needing to nest all visible blocks under sections.
To visualize:
in the following screenshot, the entire red part is hidden, but I want to be able to only hide the green part:

Is there some trick to make it possible?
